# what is wrong with my guessing game

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# this programe random numbers between 1 and 100. 
clear
echo "Hello, "${USER}
date;
n1=$[($RANDOM % 100) +1]
guess=1
echo -n "I'm think of a number between 1 and 100. guess:"

while read n2; do
if   [[ $n2 -eq $n1 ]]; then
break;
else
echo

if [[ $n2 -gt $n1 ]]; then
echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too high. guess new:"
elif [[ $n2 -lt $n1 ]]; then
echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too low. guess new:"
fi
fi
guess=$((guess+1))
done
echo
echo "congratulation! you win."
echo

read -p "do you want to try again (y/n)?" choice
```

Comment: You tell us. What does it do and what do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Your script works apart from the fact that it does nothing with the answer to the last question. Did you perhaps forget to make it executable before running it?

Comment: Please ask these question in general stack overflow forum. Ask Ubuntu forum is meant for Ubuntu related questions. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have a `while loop` your script for your Yes / No asking.  I have added one to the bottom so that the script can loop until the answer is `N` or `n`.  I am "guessing" that you are after something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this program random numbers between 1 and 100. 
clear
echo "Hello, "${USER}
date;
guess=1
## Start loop of game here
while true; do
n1=$(( ( RANDOM % 100 ) +1 ))
echo -n "I'm think of a number between 1 and 100. Guess: "

while read n2; do
    if [[ $n2 -eq $n1 ]]; then
        break;
    else
        if [[ $n2 -gt $n1 ]]; then
            echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too high. Guess again: "
        elif [[ $n2 -lt $n1 ]]; then
            echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too low. Guess again: "
        fi
    fi
    guess=$(( $guess + 1 ))
done
echo
echo "Congratulations! You win!"
if [[ $guess == 1 ]]; then
    echo "It took you $guess guess to get $n1."
else
    echo "It took you $guess guesses to get $n1."
fi
echo

read -p "Do you want to try again (y/n)? " choice
case $choice in
    [Yy]* ) guess=1;;
    [Nn]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
esac
## End loop of game here
done
```

Example:

```
$ ./guess.bsh 
Hello, terrance
Thu Jan 10 13:27:39 MST 2019
I'm think of a number between 1 and 100. Guess: 75
Sorry, your guess is too high. Guess again: 50
Sorry, your guess is too high. Guess again: 25
Sorry, your guess is too high. Guess again: 10

Congratulations! You win!
It took you 4 guesses to guess 10.

Do you want to try again (y/n)? n
```

Comment: @DoneChild You're welcome!  =)

Comment: @DoneChild if this answer helps, don't forget to [accept](/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**